# Jest/React. How to call a function inside expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith()?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So, I need to make the `function` callback inside `setInteval` during testing the component throw Jest environment. But for now I always gets `an error message` on string `expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(timer()), 20000)` that:

> Expected mock function to have been last called with:
>             undefined
>           as argument 1, but it was called with
>             [Function anonymous].

I really cannot understand how to pass my function `_startPoolingTimer` from component to the tests in `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith`...

I'll be grateful for any help

---

TEST FILE:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import initialState, { attemptButtonActive } from './mocks/row'
import Row from '../Row'

describe('<Row />', () => {
  it('timer should start, make pooling request and after 20000 mc make pool request again', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    const Component = mount(<Row {...initialState} />)
    const { poollingTimerId, count } = Component.instance().state
    const timer = Component.instance()._startPoolingTimer

    expect(count).toBe(1)
    expect(poollingTimerId).toBeTruthy()
    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(timer()), 20000)
    expect(count).toBe(9)
  })
})
```

COMPONENT FILE:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

export class Row extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      poollingTimerId: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let poollingTimerId = setInterval(this._startPoolingTimer, 20000)
  }

  _startPoolingTimer = () => {
    const { startPooling, additionalInfoGlobal } = this.props
    const moneyFromServer = additionalInfoGlobal.moneyToCollect
    startPooling()

    this.setState({
      count: moneyFromServer
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Row {...props}>
          {'hh'}
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

export default Row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export class Row4Collect extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      poollingTimerId: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let poollingTimerId = setInterval(this.props._startPoolingTimer, 20000)
  }

  _startPoolingTimer = () => {
    const { startPooling, additionalInfoGlobal } = this.props
    const moneyFromServer = additionalInfoGlobal.moneyToCollect
    startPooling()

    this.setState({
      count: moneyFromServer
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Row {...props}>
          {'hh'}
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
         _startPoolingTimer: () => this._startPoolingTimer()
    }
}

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps )(Row);
```

Update it like this.

When you are done with updating then use spy for the prop and test your function.

Your test would look like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Row from '../Row'

describe('<Row />', () => {
  it('timer should start, make pooling request and after 20000 mc make pool request again', () => {
    const spyFn = jest.fn();
    const Component = mount(<Row {...initialState} _startPoolingTimer= {spyFn} />)
    expect(spyFn).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith();


  })
})
```

I have done this in jest.

Comment: I do not need `redux` for this. Thank you, but this solution is overkill

Comment: So, you think this is normal to make the `redux` implementation in app just for to solving the problem with Jest testing for single component? It's ridiculous